# C# Outlook Addin - Open msg Files

Tags: c#, outlook, add-in

Ok i try to explain the Problem.

I've wrote an Outlook Extension to match Mails, Task and so on to an ERP System.

It works just fine but i have 1 Problem:

I save all Outlook Elements whitch could be mapped to ERP Customers, Suplliers and so on in the Document Database of the ERP System. So Every Project/Team member could open the latest Version of the Outlook Item.

The first time a user Opens the Item every Thing is fine, the second time they couldn't open the File because it is already open in Outlook.

see [social.msdn.microsoft.com](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/17e93516-e6c6-4b31-a713-d49f836479df/sessionopenshareditem-for-opening-msg-files-showing-error-in-outlook-c?forum=outlookdev)

I know that Outlook "saves" a temporay item for every msg File but i could not release the object.

And i don't want to Quit Outlook i just want to release the msg File after closing it so the User can reopen it WITHOUT CLOSING Outlook.

But i haven't found a way to release it without calling Quit.

Or is there an Option to redisplay the the currently opend Item? At the Moment i have no idea how to reference those already opened msg files.

Building an Dictionary of those Item is quite heavy i think.

@SuperBiasedMan - Sure, i tried 2 ways so far:

```
// 1. Just open File in corresponding Viewer   
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start([PathToMsgFile]);
// 2. Using SharedItem Method to get an item Object 
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();

var item = app.Session.OpenSharedItem([PathToMsgFile]) as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem;
item.Display();
```

With both the Item is Displayed as expected, when the User Closes this File and try to reopen it (without restarting Outlook)the user get an error Message:

> "Cannot open file: [PathToMsgFile] .msg. The file may not exist, you may not have permission to open it, or it may be open in another program. Right-click the folder that contains the file, and then click Properties to check your permissions for the folder."

Outlook keeps the Item open.
The only way i found to release it is to call:

```
app.Quit();
```

The Discussions (see Link above) conclusion is that Outlook "saves" an temporary Outlook Element when opening Msg files. I search an possibility to close/delete/release or whatever this temporary Object or to reopen it without restarting Outlook

@Dmitry: The file comes from a remote machine

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post the code you've written, it's usually not possible to answer a question without seeing your code.

Comment: The same instance of Outlook should have to problem reopening an MSG file even if it is already open/referenced as long as it is really the same instance and the security context is the same. Is that a local MSG file or does it come from a remote machine?

Comment: In the Related Question Section i found: [OpenSharedItem for opening .MSG files showing Error in Outlook C#](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14439689/5219524)

Comment: I tried the Suggestion in the Article above. As Described in the Question calling Quit() Method is not Working here. Setting the Files to ReadOnly works but it is a big Overhead to set the the file Writeable for every Synchronization Process and set it back to ReadOnly afterwards.